# How do you keep an application in the dock in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: dock

When I open an application it appears in the lower part of the dock, but it disappears when I quit it and it would be useful if it could stay there.

MacOS and Windows have had this feature for years; does Ubuntu not? It certainly doesn't seem to -- only what's in there by default.

When I right click a running application there is no option to keep it there -- only *all windows* and *quit*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `waffle` menu 'Show Applications' at the bottom corner of the dock, then right click on the application and select 'Add to Favourites'.

Comment: That does it; thank you :)

Next problem: when I open an application that is in my dock favourites the lower part of the dock gets a second icon for it. Can it be made to have only one dock icon?

Comment: No, as far as I know, the second icon appears when the application is running. But for Firefox the dot left to icon appears. I don't know why.